# Java how to store more than one string variable

Tags: java

I want to get information from the user like last name, first name, and id number for example `Smith, John 12345` and continue looping until the user enters "exit". Whenever I enter two inputs the first one gets wiped out and the second one is stored. Maybe I should be using a different approach then what I have...

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(reader);

String inputValues;
String person;
String lastname = "";
String firstname = "";
String id = "";

while(true){

    inputValues = input.readLine();
    person = inputValues.split("\\s+");

    if(inputValues.equals("exit"){
        break;
    }

    else {
        lastname = person[0];
        firstname = person[1];
        id = person[2];
    }
}
```

I know my program is wrong but this is what I have thus far. I do not know how to store multiple people to eventually print out their names and id at the end of this.

Comment: This won't compile. You need to change `person` to be an array of Strings to conform the the `split()` return type

Comment: beside what kon mentioned it is clear why, but I am curious to know how you print your data?

Comment: @kon I know this is not fully correct but I am trying to get the concept of Storing the first input `Smith, John 12345` and the also being able to store another input like `Rogers, Bob 54321` and then printing out both of their names and ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand your problem correct: your problem is that you overwrite your old entries? To prevent that you have to use some kind of array or list.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(reader);

        String inputValues;
        String[] person;
        List<String> lastname = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> firstname = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> id = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(true){
            inputValues = input.readLine();
            person = inputValues.split("\\s+");
            if(inputValues.equals("exit")){
              break;
            }else{
                lastname.add(person[0]);
                firstname.add(person[1]);
                id.add(person[2]);
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<lastname.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(firstname.get(i) +" "+ lastname.get(i) +" ("+ id.get(i) +")");
    }
}
```

See here: https://ideone.com/l1TnF8

Comment: Separate lists for first name, last name and id? Well, then let's hope no one will manipulate a single list.

Comment: Ofcourse in a real application you should wrap them - but it seems like the problem is the fundamental understanding, so I want to keep the solution as simple as possible.

Comment: Thanks @Verim this is what I wast trying to learn. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just as kon has noted you need an array of strings for person, what is happening is that each time you input a new value the new one only replaces the old one since person is only a string occupying just one memory space.